# Flutter: Google Maps. How can I pass both of these marker types?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating two marker types. One from Bloc and via a consumer, and the other from my main class. How can I set markers: to accept both Provmap.markers and Set.of(markers.values)? Google map code below:

```
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                  .size
                  .width, // or use fixed size like 200
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child:
                  Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, Provmap, widget) {
                return GoogleMap(
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    compassEnabled: true,
                    mapToolbarEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                    onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
                    onLongPress: _addMarkerLongPressed,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                    mapType: maptype,
                    onTap: Provmap.addMarker,


//                    markers: Provmap.markers,  ///cant pass both... 
                      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),

                    
                    circles: Set<Circle>.of(circles.values),
                    polylines: Provmap.polyline,
                    polygons: Provmap.polygon,
                    initialCameraPosition:
                        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 10.0),
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                      mapController = controller;
                      _controller.complete(controller);
                      isMapCreated = true;
                      changeMapMode();
                      changeMapType();
                      setState(() {});
                      Provmap.onCreated;
                    });
              })),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `markers.values` is not `Set` make set with `toSet()` likes `markers.values.toSet()`.
And use `union()` in `Set`.

It would be like `markers.values.toSet().union(Provmap.markers)`

And `Provmap.markers` should to be `Set` also. Cause the `union()` takes a `Set` type for It's argument.

Comment: You saved me so much headache. Thank you so much... Do you have a tip jar?

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand “have a tip jar”. Cause my English skill is not good...

Comment: It's okay. In the USA, we like giving people money (tips) to show appreciation or for excellent service. I've seen tip jars on stack overflow although I'm not sure if it goes against their terms. Alternative names for tip jars include "buy me coffee" or "buy me a drink" buttons. If you had one, i'd definitely tip for your help with my last issue. Thanks again